# When using the Ember sortBy method with multiple arguments how do i reverse one argument and not the other?

Tags: ember.js

Lets say I have a route such as

```
/routes/pets.js

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('pet').then(function(pets) {
      return pets.sortBy('name', 'ownerName');
    });
  }
});
```

Which will sort by name and then orderName. But what if I wanted to sort by one property ascending and one descending?

It is easy enough to do one descending, like so:

```
return pets.sortBy('name').reverse();
```

But I can't see how to do with with 2 or more arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried it but I believe you could do that:

```
// route
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('pet');
  }
});

// controller
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  customSorting: ['name', 'ownerName:desc'],
  sortedPets: Ember.computed.sort('model', 'customSorting')
});
```

Otherwise simply implement your custom sorting function, as explained in the docs: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_sort